# How to get JMeter to report the time each http/jdbc request/sample took

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to report back on each request/sample in my jmeter test.
I have 1 thread group setup, number of users is 1 and loop count is 5.
Inside the thread group I have 5 different http/jdbc requests that read from csv data set config files.  I'm ok getting an overview of the min, max and average times.  But I also (more importantly) want to know how long each request took.  Based on my config above I want 25 lines telling me that the request/sample took x time.

The report I get at the end shows the average time, min time max time for each request.  But I want it to show each sample for each request.  I want to know that request 1 sample 1 took 4 minutes, request 1 sample 2 took 3 minutes, etc.  Be able to expand # of Samples or something.

I'm looking for a report like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details of each sampler request if you run your test with -l option and save results in jtl file.

The command should look like : 
**jmeter.sh -n -t "path to your jmeter script" -l log.jtl**

At the end of the test, jtl file will save every request made, response time for each request, response code, response message.

or

Add Simple Data Writer in your JMeter script. Mention csv file name. At the end of the test CSV file will have details of each request made to the server during test.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.  I updated the question to show the image of what information and what report I'm looking for.  How is that possible?